# Missing samples applications for reverse binding

Tags: go, gomobile

How to work with reverse binding in gomobile.
I can not find any sample application to do so.
https://github.com/golang/mobile/tree/master/example

**Is anybody tried the reverse binding samples in gomobile ..**
What are the steps involved ?